# How to replace data in one pandas df by the data of another one?

Tags: python, pandas

Want to replace some rows of some columns in a bigger pandas df by data in a smaller pandas df. The column names are same in both.
Tried using combine_first but it only updates the null values.

For example lets say df1.shape is 100, 25 and df2.shape is 10,5
df1

```
A   B     C    D     E     F  G ...Z  Y  Z
1  abc  10.20  0   pd.NaT
```

df2

```
A   B      C    D  E
1  abc  15.20   1  10
```

Now after replacing df1 should look like:

```
A   B     C    D   E   F  G ...Z  Y  Z
1  abc  15.20  1   10 ...
```

To replace values in df1 the condition is where df1.A = df2.A and df1.B = df2.B

How can it be achieved in the most pythonic way? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `df1.update(df2)`?

Comment: `@Quang Hoang` Can u plz provide an example of update () by using the conditions that I mentioned? I don't think simply doing df1.update(df2) will help.

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. `update` aligns `index/columns` So you may want to set `A,B` as index on both dataframe. Otherwise, I think you need a merge.

Comment: Also `pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['A','B']).first()`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know I really understood your question does this solves your problem ?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1],'B':[2],'C':[3],'D':[4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1],'B':[2],'C':[5],'D':[6]})

new_df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(['A','B'],keep='last')
print(new_df)
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play with Multiindex.
First let us create those dataframe that you are working with:

```py
cols = pd.Index(list(ascii_uppercase))
vals = np.arange(100*len(cols)).reshape(100, len(cols))

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=cols)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vals[:10,:5], columns=cols[:5])
```

Then transform A and B in indices:

```py
df = df.set_index(["A","B"])
df1 = df1.set_index(["A","B"])*1.5 # multiply just to make the other values different

df.loc[df1.index, df1.columns] = df1
df = df.reset_index()
```